# Why is the extension in the rod not same in both case?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, elasticity, stress-strain

I know that when you pull a rod from one end as shown in the figure [image]

such that it is accelerating on a smooth horizontal floor with no friction, the average tension would be $F\over{2}$. And So stress will be $F\over{2A}$, where $A$ is the area of cross-section of the rod

But what if the force acted on the center S?[image]

I assumed that the first half to be A and second had to be B. [image: ⁷]

There will be no effect of this force on the A. So

$$F_{av}= \frac{ \int_0 ^{\frac{l}{2}} \frac{\frac{l}{2}-x}{\frac{l}{2}}dx}{\int_0 ^{\frac{l}{2}} dx}$$

> Where $l$ is length of the rod

Which again gives $F_{av}= \frac{F}{2A}$

But the difference in both is the extension in the rod due to stress is double in the first case to that of the second one.

Why is this happening? Should the part A also get affected by this force?

Comment: What makes you think the tension is F/2?

Comment: @BobD by integration similar to that I mentioned in second case.

Comment: I don’t understand your integrand

Comment: Why do you think that part A is not affected?

Comment: @Siddharth The link you gave in your comment to my answer was for an accelerating rod. My answer is for a rod fixed at the right in equilibrium. If your question concerns an accelerating rod you should make that clear in your post because as it is now, it is not clear.

Comment: @BobD okay my bad. Now can you demonstrate a solution?

Comment: Please clarify foces/accelerations involved here. Is the rod accelerating? Is there friction (uniform, probably, same force per length touching the ground everywhere)?

Comment: And why would a force acting in the middle not affect A?? When you can pull a rod from one end, you can push it as well (the same goes for halves of the rod).

Comment: @Siddharth BTW, in the third equation in the link F/m should be F/M

Comment: @kricheli you should look at the question before commenting. I edited it yesterday before your comment.

Comment: @kricheli why would it. It's a smooth floor why will ti feel push or pull?

Comment: @Siddharth: If "smooth floor" implies no friction, fair enough. As for the force affecting A: it's just $F=ma$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the average stress you already have the result $\frac{F}{2A}$ for the whole rod. Which by reversing the sign also works for a rod being pushed instead of being pulled. Now consider the example with the force acting in the middle: Half of the force is pushing A, half is pulling B, so using the previous result we find the average stress $\frac{F}{4A}$ for each half of the rod and thus for the whole rod. (Which is, of course, for the average absolute value of the stress. If you include the sign, the average value over the whole beam will be zero. A is being compressed, B is being stretched and thus the deformations have different signs in the two halves.)